# I'm getting the following error from the CursorAdapter Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

My Binder Class

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


            mTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_title);
            mDateAndTimeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_date_time);
            mRepeatInfoText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_repeat_info);
            mActiveImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.active_image);
            mThumbnailImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_image);

           int titleColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE);
            int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE);
            int timeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME);
            int repeatColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT);
            int repeatNoColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_NO);
            int repeatTypeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_TYPE);
            int activeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE);
            int locationColumnIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_LOCATION);

            String title = cursor.getString(titleColumnIndex);
            String date = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
            String time = cursor.getString(timeColumnIndex);
            String repeat = cursor.getString(repeatColumnIndex);
            String repeatNo = cursor.getString(repeatNoColumnIndex);
            String repeatType = cursor.getString(repeatTypeColumnIndex);
            String active = cursor.getString(locationColumnIndex);
            String loc = cursor.getString(activeLocation);
            String dateTime = date + " " + time;
            Log.e("msg_fa", loc);
            if (loc.equals(false)) {
                setReminderTitle(title);
                setReminderDateTime(dateTime);
                setReminderRepeatInfo(repeat, repeatNo, repeatType);
                setActiveImage(active);

            } else
            {
                setReminderTitle(title);
                setReminderDateTime("Place");
            }

    }
```

**My Logcat Error**

```
         E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 8 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 8 columns.
            2018-10-24 19:54:06.958 11109-11109/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process:PID: 11109
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 8 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

**I can access the till data columnIndex 7 but i cant get the index from 8**

**Code for My DB HELPER**

```
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the reminder table
            String SQL_CREATE_ALARM_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE + " TEXT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME + " TEXT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT + " TEXT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_NO + " TEXT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE + " TEXT,"
                    +AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.latitude+" TEXT ,"
                    + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.longitude+" TEXT" +" );";

            // Execute the SQL statement
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ALARM_TABLE);
```

**Insertion to the database works perfectly but this issue comes when i ask to fetch the data from the 8th index**

The main issue which I'm facing is when I try to get the value from the index of KEY_LOCATION the app crashes and it then gives out the error which is displayed in the logcat I'm getting the value till column 7 I tried updating the database version and changing the table name and database name it didn't work as expected.

Here is my Provider Class

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                        String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // This cursor will hold the result of the query
        Cursor cursor = null;

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case REMINDER:
                cursor = database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null, null, sortOrder);
                Log.i("msg","Reminder Invoked");
                break;
            case REMINDER_ID:
                selection = AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };


                cursor = database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
        }
```

Comment: Put your cursor query first.and also the looping code of cursor

Comment: The issue is likely going to be either that you haven't changed the table structure (although you say you have updated the database version) or that the query that gets the Cursor is not selecting the KEY_LOCATIONS column (SELECT * FROM ........ will select all columns). I'd suggest deleting the App's data (that would rule out the onUpgrade method not being suitable) and then rerunning. If the issue still persists then edit your question to include the query that returns the Cursor.

Comment: I'm not using any loop I'm directly fetching the column index the insertion is working perfectly and while fetching the data I'm just taking the index value. I tried deleting the app and the database got updated. As I mentioned earlier I can fetch data from index 8. Index 0-7 works perfectly

Comment: So why are you not editing your question to include the query, which would be the most likely issue?

Comment: As per your request I have updated the question

Comment: @AmrudeshBalakrishnan *the insertion is working perfectly* so you can insert rows with values in the 8-10 columns? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: The insertion is working perfectly in 8-10 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Cursor only has 8 (offsets 0-7) of the 11 (offsets 0-10) columns in the table. Hence the message saying that it has failed to read row 0 (the first row) column 8 (the 9th column (location)).

A Cursor will only contain the columns that you specify implicitly or explicitly (SELECT * implies all columns, null as the 2nd parameter to the SQLIteDatabase query method equates to SELECT * and thus implies all columns). This irrespective of the columns in the underlying table or tables.

You issue would appear to be that the String array passed to the Provider Class's as the 2nd parameter (projection) only explicitly specifies 8 columns.

A quick fix (although the most flexible fix) would be to use **null** insetad of **projection** as the 2nd parameter when calling the SQLiteDatabase **query** method.

So instead of :-

```
database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
```

You could use :-

```
database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
```

As such the entire query method could be :-

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // This cursor will hold the result of the query
    Cursor cursor = null;

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case REMINDER:
            cursor = database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, 
                    null, //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED 
                    selection, 
                    selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            Log.i("msg","Reminder Invoked");
            break;
        case REMINDER_ID:
            selection = AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };


            cursor = database.query(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.TABLE_NAME, 
                    null, //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED 
                    selection, 
                    selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }
}
```

- Note the 2nd parameter `String[] projection` passed to the method would be redundant.

An alternative would be to amend the call to the Provider class's **query** method (as above) so that the String array passed includes the extra column(s) when invoking the Provider class's **query** method.

e.g.

```
String[] projection_columns = new String[]{
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_NO,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_TYPE,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_LOCATION,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.latitude,
    AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.longitude
}

your_provider.query(your_uri, project_columns,your_selection, your_selectionargs, you_sortorder);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help It got fixed. As you mentioned above i forgot to declare them in the projection